# Titles fadein on window open

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

First post for me there, I'll start by thanking this awesome community for the help I've found for years now.

I've handled multiple pieces of javascript code without getting an overview of the language, sorry for that. My question is I guess basic but this time I don't find the answer by myself..

I have those two div on the homepage of my site

```css
.MainTitle {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    padding:0;
    width:50%;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight:300;
    color: #2f3542;
    text-align:center;
}
.SubTitle {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;   
    padding:0;
    width:50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight:300;
    color: lightgrey;
    text-align:center;
}
.country {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;   
    padding:0;
    width:50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight:300;
    color: lightgrey;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainTitle">
    HERE MAIN TITLE
</div>
<div class="SubTitle">
    <span class="country"><a href="fr/pages/about.php">FR</a></span>
    <span> | </span>
    <span class="country"><a href="fr/pages/about.php">EN</span>    
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is to :
1. Fade-in the Maintitle with a timing and an opacity that I can set ;
2. Also fade-in the Subtitle with timing/opacity but once the Maintitle has been has showed up

I want those two action to be automatically triggered once the page is loaded. Maybe timing before Maintitle fadein and between Maintitle and Subtitle fade-in can be useful.

Thanks a lot if someone can help me on that !

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
div {
    display:none;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="MainTitle">
        HERE MAIN TITLE
    </div>
    <div class="SubTitle">
    <span class="country"><a href="fr/pages/about.php">FR</a></span>
    <span> | </span>
    <span class="country"><a href="fr/pages/about.php">EN</span>    
    </div>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.MainTitle, .SubTitle').each(function(fadeInDiv){
     $(this).delay(fadeInDiv * 500).fadeIn(1000);
   });
});

    });
  </script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: If this answer is useful please review it. So , We can give answer with more clearity